# AudioTrack signal generator listening from gyroscope

Tags: java, android, generator, wave, audiotrack

I am trying to create signal generator which frequency is controlled from gyroscope senzor data (by moving the phone). The problem is, I am calling the `AudioTrack` inside `onSensorChanged` and I have "clicks" on the output, because every time the senzor is updated, I call

```
stopSinus();
setSinus(Frequency);
startSinus();
```

it is defined like this

```
 siAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE,
 AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
 buffsize, AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

public void stopSinus() {
        int checkPlay = siAudioTrack.getPlayState();
        if (checkPlay == 3) {  //
         siaudioTrack.stop();
         }
}

public void startSinus() {
        siAudioTrack.reloadStaticData();
        siAudioTrack.setLoopPoints(0, sampleCount, -1);  
        siAudioTrack.play();

}

public void setSinus(int frequency) {

    sampleCount = (int) ((float) SAMPLE_RATE / frequency);
    short sample[] = new short[sampleCount];
    int amplitude = 32767;
    double twoPi = 2 * Math.PI;;
    double phase = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++) {
        sample[i] = (short) (amplitude * Math.sin(phase));
        phase += twoPi * frequency / SAMPLE_RATE;
    }
    siAudioTrack.write(sample, 0, sampleCount);
}
```

`onSensorChanged` changes several times per second and it will stop the generator in the midle of wave - thats where the "clicks" goes from.

Can someone tell me how to stop the generator after one whole wave? How to find out when `phase` os passing zero? Or some different solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no practical way to determine when the phase being applied to the speaker is passing 0. Best to just give up on that.

Here's a "different" solution which I think you will find works much better:

1. Switch to `MODE_STREAM`. For the lowest latency, use the smallest available buffer size (`getMinBufferSize()`).
2. Use a dedicated thread to supply a waveform to the `AudioTrack`. This thread has one job: writing little pieces of waveform to the `AudioTrack`, based on the current frequency. (You could also use the main thread, and constantly pepper the `AudioTrack` with non-blocking writes, but in my opinion using a separate thread is more elegant. The thread will spend most of its time stuck inside a blocking `write()` call, meaning that the buffer stays maximally filled, with minimal work.)
3. Get rid of `startSinus()` and `stopSinus()`. Start audio playback at the beginning, and don't stop it until you leave the app.
4. Change `setSinus()` so that it simply communicates the current frequency value to the thread described in step 2. Use any standard inter-thread communication mechanism.
5. When it's time to leave the app, use a standard inter-thread communication mechanism to inform the thread it should terminate, then `join()` it, clean up, etc.

Additional details:

- Make your `write()s` small. Maybe just 100 samples at a time. This helps to minimize latency while still maintaining desirable blocking behavior, and avoids the need to worry about how much free space is available in the `AudioTrack`.
- In the worker thread, use a `float` to keep track of phase (much like you are doing now). Increment the phase based on the frequency, but don't let it get too big! Keep it between 0 and 2*PI by letting it wrap (otherwise, large phase errors will creep in due to quantization, and the frequency will change unexpectedly). Obviously, you don't reset `phase` after you fill each tiny 100-sample buffer. You just let it keep rollin' around.